# Error on Login-Page "Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"

Tags: php, mysqli

I am currently making a website for a school project and I am making a user registration system. Currently, the sign-up portion works perfectly with user data going into the MySQL database. However, my login-page seems to be broken. Every time I try to log-in I get the following error:

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\hennorist\login.php on line 23

Attached is the PHP code in question:

```
<?php
    
require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";

$error = '';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    
    //validate if email is empty
    if (empty($email)) {
        $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter email.</p>';
    }
    
    if (empty($error)) {
        if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
            $query->bind_param('s', $email);
            $query->execute();
            $row = $query->fetch();
            if ($row) {
                if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                    $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION["user"] = $row;
                    
                    //Redirect user to welcome page
                    header("location: exclusive.php");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">The password is not valid.</p>';
                }
            } else {
                $error .= '<p class="error">No user exists with that email address.</p>';
            }
        }
        $query->close();
    }
    //Close connection
    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>
```

Comment: The `fetch` method is for results bound to variables, something  I personally don’t see too often these days. Instead you probably want [`get_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Comment: `$row = $query->fetch();` -- that is not [how `fetch()` works](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). `$row` will be true, false or null. You're getting this warning because you're trying to access `$row['password']`, which is the same as `true['password']` -- or, *trying to access array offset* ("password") *on a value of type bool* ($row).

Answer (score -1):

Are you forced to work with the PDO driver? as a beginner it will be a little tricky for you but I would suggest you to work with MySQLi instead,

In your included file for connexion (guess config.php) to database make sure your connexion is instancing the PDO class as
$query = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

Then to close connexion use $query = null; instead of mysqli_close($db);

Assume you understood try executing the following code

```
 <?php
    
require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";

$error = '';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    
    //validate if email is empty
    if (empty($email)) {
        $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter email.</p>';
    }
    
    if (empty($error)) {
        if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
            $query->bind_param('s', $email);
            $query->execute();
            $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($row) {
                if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                    $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION["user"] = $row;
                    
                    //Redirect user to welcome page
                    header("location: exclusive.php");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">The password is not valid.</p>';
                }
            } else {
                $error .= '<p class="error">No user exists with that email address.</p>';
            }
        }
    }
    //Close connection
    $query=null;
}
?>
```

Comment: The following is my config file: `<?php
define('DBSERVER', 'localhost'); //Database server
define('DBUSERNAME', 'root'); //Database username
define('DBPASSWORD',''); //Database password
define('DBNAME', 'users'); //Database name
    
/* connect to MySQL databse */
$db = mysqli_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);

//check db connection
if($db === false){
    die("Error: connection error.".mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>` I placed the PDO code in there, and replaced my login code with the one you provided, however it still did not work and threw up more errors.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. You talked about something unrelated and you didn't even fix the error from the question. It looks like you got confused between PDO and mysqli. This resulted in even worse code than what OP originally had

Comment: You are connecting with mySQLi then you want to use PDO instance,  it cant work. connect as i suggested in my answer then use PDO in your files